# error while getting Active Directory Realm with Glassfish 3.1

Tags: java, glassfish, ldap, glassfish-3

hello every one I tried to solve this issue with configuration Relam Ldap in glass fish 3.1 but I get this error

```
WARNING: SEC1106: Error during LDAP search with filter [uid=teuser].
WARNING: SEC1000: Caught exception.
javax.naming.NamingException: [LDAP: error code 1 - 000004DC: LdapErr: DSID-0C0906E8, comment: In order to perform this operation a successful bind must be completed on the connection., data 0, v1db1]; remaining name= 'DC=dev,DC=tcs,DC=com'
WARNING: WEB9102: Web Login Failed: com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.common.LoginException: Login failed: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: User MyUserName not found.
```

the web.xml looks like this :

```
<security-constraint>
<display-name>Constraint1</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Simple Web Resource</web-resource-name>
        <description/>
        <url-pattern>*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
</security-constraint>

<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <realm-name>ldapRealm</realm-name>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/index.jsp</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/error.xhtml</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>
```

the domain.xml in glassfish directory :

```
<auth-realm name="ldapRealm" classname="com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.ldap.LDAPRealm">
      <property name="directory" value="ldap://10.0.???.???:389"></property>
      <property name="base-dn" value="DC=dev,DC=tcs,DC=com"></property>
      <property name="jaas-context" value="ldapRealm"></property>
    </auth-realm>
```

I need to know what that error is it problem in configuration at glassfish or what ?

Answer (score 1):

I hit this one when I was not specifying correct credentials for an Active Directory server. Specify the credentials as additional realm properties:

1. search-bind-dn for username
2. search-bind-password for a password